# Django Admin page error with MySQL

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some issue with connecting my Django 2.0 with MySql:

When I am checking my localhost on xampp server locally, it looks data entered and connected with my project but the below is the error that showing when I want to see my admin page:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/
(1146, "Table 'scdemployees.django_session' doesn't exist")
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
(1146, "Table 'scdemployees.django_session' doesn't exist")
Exception Location: C:\Users\Janahi\venv\Django_me\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py in query, line 277
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Janahi\venv\Django_me\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Janahi\\PycharmProjects\\Django_me',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2017.3\\helpers\\pycharm',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\PycharmProjects\\Django_me',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\venv\\Django_me\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\venv\\Django_me',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\venv\\Django_me\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\venv\\Django_me\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Janahi\\venv\\Django_me\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg']
Server time:    Fri, 16 Feb 2018 15:04:28 +0000
```

Comment: did you run `python manage.py migrate` ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using database Django session backend so you should do as [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions) documentation regarding following states

> #### Using database-backed sessions
>
> If you want to use a database-backed
>   session, you need to add `'django.contrib.sessions'` to your
>   `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.
>
> Once you have configured your installation, run `manage.py migrate` to
>   install the single database table that stores session data.